# Remove any string starting with a square bracket

Tags: r, regex

I have the following vector in R:

```
myvec <- c("1.80 m (5 ft 11 in)[2]", "1.81 m (5 ft 11 1⁄2 in)[2]", "1.86 m (6 ft 1 in)[2]", "1.75 m (5 ft 9 in)[2][3][4]")
```

I want to remove anything that starts with "[", inclusive, so that I end up with:

```
myvec_clean <- c("1.80 m (5 ft 11 in)", "1.81 m (5 ft 11 1⁄2 in)", "1.86 m (6 ft 1 in)", "1.75 m (5 ft 9 in)")
```

I've tried the following but it's only removing the first case:

```
gsub("\\[[\\d-]\\]+", "", myvec)
```

Comment: `gsub("\\[[^]]*]","",myvec)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gsub("\\[[^\\]]+\\]", "", myvec, perl=T)
```

This removes anything inside square brackets, including the brackets. It should yield the following:

```
# [1] "1.80 m (5 ft 11 in)"     "1.81 m (5 ft 11 1⁄2 in)" "1.86 m (6 ft 1 in)"      "1.75 m (5 ft 9 in)"
```

I hope this helps.